# Azure Function app (V3, nodejs) has no function after zip deployment

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Function Nodejs linux with programming Model V3.

Note it is V3, not V4;

I have followed docs:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript%2Clinux%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v3#configure-function-entry-point
2. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push.md

Here is the project:

```
<root-directory>
├── README.md
├── dist
├── azure_function.zip
├── bin
├── dependencies
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── sealworker
│   ├── constants
│   ├── errors
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── interfaces
│   ├── sample.dat
│   ├── sealworkerfunction.ts
│   ├── services
│   ├── utils
│   └── worker.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Here is the `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/sealworker/index.ts"
}
```

Here is the `index.ts`:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { workerExec } from "./worker";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  const name = req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name);
  const responseMessage = name
    ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the req body for a personalized response.";

  context.log(`Http function processed req for url "${req.url}"`);
  const x = req.body;
  context.log("x: ", x);

  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: responseMessage,
  };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Here is the `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

However, after zip deployment, there is no function in the azure function app portal.

I can confirm that the storage associated with the azure function has the correct code uploaded in `site/wwwroot`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Add the setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in *Function App=>settings=>configuration=>Add New Application settings* and re-deploy your application. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/wffXKUt.png)

Comment: @PravallikaKV   you saved me!  I wonder why they don't say this in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as answer for community:

- When you deploy your function as zip package, the deployment engine doesn't run any build automation as it assumes that a ZIP file is ready to run.

To see the deployed function in the function app,

Go to your Function App=>Settings=>Configuration=>Add Application Settings, click on Add:

- Add the setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` . This is to enable remote build process on ***Linux function app***.

[image]

- Re-deploy your application to function app.
- Now, you will be able to see your function in the ***Portal=>Function App.***

**References:**

[Zip push deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-customization)

Comment: or just `func azure functionapp publish YourFunctionApp --build=remote`